# USB Wi-Fi Adapter work in computer's port, but not in powered USB hub

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, 22.10

I am working to attach the Netgear AXE3000 Wi-Fi 6 adapter to a Ubuntu 22.10 system. Background on this particular adapter [here](https://github.com/morrownr/USB-WiFi/blob/main/home/USB_WiFi_Adapters_that_are_supported_with_Linux_in-kernel_drivers.md).

The adapter works when plugged directly into the host computer (Dell 7490). However when plugged into [a USB 3.0 hub](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0797NZFYP) the adapter is not available in `ip a`.

Here's the output of lsusb, with two adapters detected:

```
lsusb
        Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0846:9060 NetGear, Inc. Wireless_Device
        Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0846:9060 NetGear, Inc. Wireless_Device
        Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Hub
        Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
        Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0032 Intel Corp. AX210 Bluetooth
        Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:568c Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated Webcam HD
        Bus 001 Device 013: ID 1546:01a7 U-Blox AG [u-blox 7]
        Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5411 Hub
        Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0a5c:5834 Broadcom Corp. 5880
        Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here is the output of `lsusb -v`

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0846:9060 NetGear, Inc. Wireless_Device
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.20
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x0846 NetGear, Inc.
  idProduct          0x9060 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           2 MediaTek Inc.
  iProduct                3 Wireless_Device
  iSerial                 4 000000000
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0087
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          5 Config_01
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              160mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           9
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              1 WiFi_If
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x85  EP 5 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x08  EP 8 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x05  EP 5 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x06  EP 6 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x07  EP 7 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x09  EP 9 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x86  EP 6 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0002  1x 2 bytes
        bInterval               1
        bMaxBurst               0
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength       0x0016
  bNumDeviceCaps          2
  USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      2
    bmAttributes   0x0000f11e
      BESL Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
    BESL value      256 us 
    Deep BESL value    61440 us 
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x00
    wSpeedsSupported   0x000e
      Device can operate at Full Speed (12Mbps)
      Device can operate at High Speed (480Mbps)
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   1
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is Full Speed (12Mbps)
    bU1DevExitLat          10 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat         180 micro seconds
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

When I perform `lsusb -v` with the adapters plugged into the computer and then again with the adapters plugged into the hub, only two lines are different:

In the computer:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0846:9060 NetGear, Inc. Wireless_Device
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0846:9060 NetGear, Inc. Wireless_Device
```

In the hub:

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0846:9060 NetGear, Inc. Wireless_Device
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0846:9060 NetGear, Inc. Wireless_Device
```

I tried `sudo dmesg` to see what the kernel reported when the hub and adapters were plugged in.

```
$ sudo dmesg
[ 5536.142808] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[ 5536.306322] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=5411, bcdDevice= 0.02
[ 5536.306336] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 5536.306343] usb 1-2: Product: USB2.1 Hub
[ 5536.306348] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 5536.309113] hub 1-2:1.0: USB hub found
[ 5536.311361] hub 1-2:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 5536.423324] usb 2-3: new SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 5536.454878] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0411, bcdDevice= 0.02
[ 5536.454883] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 5536.454884] usb 2-3: Product: USB3.2 Hub
[ 5536.454886] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 5536.463531] hub 2-3:1.0: USB hub found
[ 5536.465082] hub 2-3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 5536.610586] usb 1-2.3: new full-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[ 5536.720847] usb 1-2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=2303, bcdDevice= 4.00
[ 5536.720853] usb 1-2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 5536.720856] usb 1-2.3: Product: USB-Serial Controller D
[ 5536.720858] usb 1-2.3: Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc. 
[ 5536.730208] pl2303 1-2.3:1.0: pl2303 converter detected
[ 5536.732874] usb 1-2.3: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 5536.806993] usb 2-3.1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 5536.829234] usb 2-3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0846, idProduct=9060, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 5536.829249] usb 2-3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[ 5536.829256] usb 2-3.1: Product: Wireless_Device
[ 5536.829261] usb 2-3.1: Manufacturer: MediaTek Inc.
[ 5536.829266] usb 2-3.1: SerialNumber: 000000000
[ 5536.829555] usb 2-3.1: rejected 1 configuration due to insufficient available bus power
[ 5536.829563] usb 2-3.1: no configuration chosen from 1 choice
[ 5536.910538] usb 1-2.4: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[ 5537.017630] usb 1-2.4: can't connect bus-powered hub to this port
[ 5537.103003] usb 2-3.2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[ 5537.125148] usb 2-3.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0846, idProduct=9060, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 5537.125164] usb 2-3.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[ 5537.125171] usb 2-3.2: Product: Wireless_Device
[ 5537.125177] usb 2-3.2: Manufacturer: MediaTek Inc.
[ 5537.125182] usb 2-3.2: SerialNumber: 000000000
[ 5537.125487] usb 2-3.2: rejected 1 configuration due to insufficient available bus power
[ 5537.125495] usb 2-3.2: no configuration chosen from 1 choice
[ 5537.215391] usb 2-3.4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
```

The issue seems to be `rejected 1 configuration due to insufficient available bus power`.

This is a powered hub with a 60W power supply connected. Is there a configuration setting available to override the apparent incorrect assumption that the hub is bus-powered?

Comment: How many devices are connected to the powered bus?  You might have too many devices connected.

Comment: As linked above, this is a 10-port USB 3 powered hub. The hub is powered with a 60W external power supply.   I have 3 devices, two Wi-Fi and one GPS.

Comment: do you know the required wattage of each wifi device and the GPS?  60W external power supply means the hub's external powered state is 60W *total* for all the USB devices, if any of them pull more than 60W when combined together there's your error.

Comment: As shown in the `lsusb -v` output above, the device reports `MaxPower 160mA`.  I'm using 2 devices.  Even if all 10 ports had a 160mA device, that would be 1.6A  (*5V = 8W)  well below 60W supply.  As a test, I plugged one Wi-Fi adapter into the hub - nothing else.  I still get the error `rejected 1 configuration due to insufficient available bus power`

Comment: I think the issue is with the dmesg:  `can't connect bus-powered hub to this port`.   Ubuntu thinks this is a "bus powered hub" when it is externally powered.  Is that something I can fix in configuration, or is the hardware defective?

Answer (score 0):

After searching and studying the USB subsystem for hours, I was getting nowhere. After concluding that the hub was reporting itself as bus-powered when it was self-powered, I went and purchased a new hub.
I found one from [Vantec](https://www.microcenter.com/product/603779/10-Port_USB_31_Hub_with_Power_Adapter) with similar capabilities.

It worked fine. No errors were reported in dmesg:

```
[59222.814154] usb 2-4.1.1: Product: USB3.0 Hub
[59222.814155] usb 2-4.1.1: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.
[59222.814157] usb 2-4.1.1: SerialNumber: 000000000
[59222.816135] hub 2-4.1.1:1.0: USB hub found
[59222.816286] hub 2-4.1.1:1.0: 4 ports detected
```

I don't know if the Sabrent hub I purchased first is a defective unit, or a defective design. I would expect it would fail on any OS, not just Linux.  I'm not sure what use a 10 port hub that could only function as bus-powered would be, though.

I'd recommend Vantec (or similar hubs using the VIA Labs chipset)